# Using the Backbone.js router on a play framework app

Tags: backbone.js, playframework-2.0, backbone-routing

I've built a simple REST API using the Play Framework 2.1 (just controllers that expects different kind of calls on different routes)

The API is already working fine but now I am trying to add a front end app using mostly JavaScript and for this purpose I want to use Backbone.js. I've started with a simple router trying to render some views but when I try to open for example the following URL:

http://somehost.com:9000/projects

It seems that it is the Play Framework router the one that is trying to resolve the URL and not the Backbone.js Router.

Is it actually possible to mix this behavior...I mean have the REST API routes to be handled by the Play Framework and have other set of routes that will be handled by the Backbone.js Router?

Comment: Have you looked at the Zentask sample? It uses Backbone.js the way you describe. Some pages are using the Play routing while some pages are using the backbone routing facilities.